# Portlet content hided when sorting in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery sortable portlets from http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets. When I am sorting the portlets the contents inside portlets hided. It is loaded properly when initializing portlets. The content hides only when sorting portlets. What is problem Here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google visualization Chart options add **'forceIFrame': false**